# How to extend the query if the sql query is parametrized?

Tags: sql, pyspark, group-by

Below is the function created to generate counts from the table, but in the query (string) I want to add 'group by' a column 'xyz'. Suggest, how to do the same.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

db = 'database'
schema = 'Schema'

def getCount(table):
    string = f"select count(*) as ct from {db}.{schema}." + table
    df = spark.read.format(snowflake_name)\
                         .options(**sfOptions)\
                         .option('query', string).load()
    return df
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one way would be to alter the f-string slightly

```py
string = f"select some_column, count(*) as ct from {db}.{schema}.{table} group by some_column"
```